# How to get back all the data after alert box?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form of 25 fields. When the error appears and the alert box shows up. and after clicking ok on the alert box all the fields became blank. How to prevent the form to become blank. I have tried so far.

```
$job_confrm = $_POST['job_confrm'];
$training_no = $_POST['training_no'];
$created_on = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$unique_id = rand(100000, 999999);

$ftquery = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * From hr_employee_service_register where employee_id='$employee_id' AND status='1'");

if (mysqli_num_rows($ftquery) > 0) {
    echo '<script>alert("Employee Already Registered");
    preventDefault();
    return false;</script>';
}
```

Comment: They don’t become blank _because_ of the alert, they become blank because you submitted the form, so a new page gets displayed, and while outputting the form again, you neglected to pre-fill the fields with the values that where input/selected/checked so far. (Please go _read up_ on how to do that, it is everything but a new topic.)

Comment: Make sure you print the values back in your form; so add a value to your form fields. Example: `<input type="text" name="employee" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['employee']?:'', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>">`

Comment: Page might have been refreshed with new HTML template without the filled-in form. 
Use AJAX or just return the HTML template with filled-in form once error appears.